# How to determine whether a piecewise function with conditions instead of equations has removable discontinuities?

Tags: calculus, continuity

I have to explain whether the piece-wise function below has any removable discontinuities. I am confused because, as far as I know, to determine whether there is a removable discontinuity, you need to have a mathematical function, not simply a condition.

Is there some way I could tell whether the function below has any removable discontinuities?

> $$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}  {1,} & {x \leq -1} \\ {-x,} & {-1 <x<0} \\ {1,} & {x=0} \\ {-x,} & {0<x<1} \\ {1,} & {x \ge 1}\end{array}\right.$$

**Graph of Function:**

[image]

Comment: What is the definition of a removable discontinuity? From that, your graph (crude or not) should readily provide the answer.

Comment: By the way this is the graph in Desmos - https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pvw7k8is42

Comment: @PeterForeman Thanks! Now I can make my own!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though it is written as a condition, $f(x)$ is in fact a function.

To find a removable discontinuity, we want to have a point such that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0+} f(x) =\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0-} f(x) \neq f(x_0)$$ where the limits are those from the left and the right.

Note that at $x=0$, we have that the limit approaching $0$ from the right of $f$ and the limit approaching $0$ from the left of $f$ are both $0$ but $f(0)=1$. Therefore there is a removable discontinuity at $x = 0$.